# Does every non-trivial $\mathbb{C}$-algebra contain an element which is not a square?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers

Let $A$ be a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra. Letting $i$ be the imaginary unit, then for each $a \in A$ we have
$$
a = \left(\frac{a-1}{2}\right)^2 + \left(i\frac{a+1}{2}\right)^2
$$
such that each element of $A$ is a sum of two squares.

Is it possible that $A$ is a non-trivial $\mathbb{C}$-algebra (i.e. not $\mathbb{C}$ or $\lbrace 0 \rbrace$) in which every element is the square of another element?

Comment: How about the algebraic closure of the polynomial algebra? Or do you want finite-dimensional examples? Do they need to be commutative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algebra $\mathbb C\times\mathbb C$ is an example.